# How to use AR QuickLook for .udsz file in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, arkit, nativescript-vue

Is there anyway to use AR QuickLook in NativeScript-Vue like this article: https://www.appcoda.com/arkit-quick-look/ ?

I tried with WebView but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [nativescript-ar](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-ar) plugin.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-ar
```

[Here is a blog post](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/getting-started-with-augmented-reality-in-nativescript) that explains how you can get started with the plugin, contains similar example like the one you have linked in your question.